# AWS S3: can I move object within a bucket by changing its key?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-js

I have a javascript lambda function that is triggered by file upload, reads the content, validates, converts data records contained therein into an array and puts data into a DynamoDB table.
When everything is OK, the file (S3 object) is moved to another folder in the same bucket - the function copies the original object to another folder and deletes the original.
This action takes some time and generates "unnecessary" data transfer.
Is there a possibility to "modify" the object key, effectively moving it?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47698644/update-aws-s3-object-key-key-name

Comment: No, copy and delete is the right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon S3 does not have a 'rename' or 'modify' function. All objects are immutable and the Key cannot be changed -- it is the unique identifier of the object.

To 'move' an object, the correct process is to `CopyObject()` and then `DeleteObject()`. This creates a *new* object with the desired Key.

Answer (score 1):

### Short Answer

Unfortunately you won't be able to get a performance boost, but you can abstract away the two operations using the S3 High-Level API

### Long Answer

AWS S3 has two APIs.

1. `s3` which is a High-Level API
2. `s3api` which is a Low-Level API

When using the **[`s3 mv`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/mv.html)** api, you may issue a command (using CLI) to move or rename (if moved to the same destination, with a different name) a file. This API is constructed to mimic the feel and outcome of the Linux `mv` command.

**Syntax:**

```s
aws s3 mv [S3ObjectSourcePath] [S3ObjectDestinationPath]
aws s3 mv [S3ObjectSourcePath] [LocalFilePath]
aws s3 mv [LocalFilePath] [S3ObjectSourcePath]
```

This is a high level API, that basically does two operations:

- `s3:ObjectCreated:Copy`
- `s3:ObjectRemoved:DeleteMarkerCreated`, but abstracts it for you.

This can be tested by creating an S3 Event Notification and running a Lambda function against those S3 Bucket events and setting up the event received to be logged in CloudWatch Logs. Then run the `mv` command and you'll see the above two operations are going to be logged per `mv` command that is successfully executed.

---

Examples:

1. **Moving a local file to S3**

   ```s
   aws s3 mv ~/hello.txt s3://my-bucket/
   ```

   **Response:**

   ```
   upload: ./hello.txt to s3://my-bucket/hello.txt
   ```
2. **Renaming a file on S3 (move to the same location)**

   ```s
   aws s3 mv s3://my-bucket/file.txt s3://my-bucket/file-moved.txt
   ```

   **Response:**

   ```
   move: s3://my-bucket/file.txt to s3://my-bucket/file-moved.txt
   ```
3. **Moving a file from S3 to S3**

   ```s
   aws s3 mv s3://my-bucket/file.txt s3://my-bucket/path/
   ```

   **Response:**

   ```
   move: s3://my-bucket/file.txt to s3://my-bucket/path/
   ```
4. **Moving an S3 object to a local file**

   ```s
   aws s3 mv s3://my-bucket/file.txt ~/file-moved-to-local.txt
   ```

   **Response:**

   ```
   download: s3://my-bucket/file.txt to ~/file-moved-to-local.txt
   ```
5. **Recursively moving S3 objects to a local directory**

   ```s
   # my-bucket contains two files: `file.txt` and `file2.txt`
   aws s3 mv s3://my-bucket . --recursive
   ```

   **Response:**

   ```
   download: s3://mybucket/file.txt to file.txt
   download: s3://mybucket/file2.txt to file2.txt
   ```
6. **Recursively moving local files to S3**

   ```s
   # `localFolder` is a local directory containing two files: `file.txt` and `file2.txt`
   aws s3 mv ~/localFolder s3://my-bucket --recursive
   ```

   **Response:**

   ```
   upload: s3TestFolder/file.txt to s3://my-bucket/file.txt
   upload: s3TestFolder/file2.txt to s3://my-bucket/file2.txt
   ```